# Training this model leads to memory leakage

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been a training a model and with htop I see that the memory keeps increasing with every iteration.Looking arround most people say that the graph must keep on growing either because I'm loading a new model with every iteration or because I add new ops, but I do none of the above.
This is the smallest reproducible example.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#%% Params
OBSERVATION_SPACE_VALUES = 4
ACTION_SPACE_SIZE = 2
LEARNING_RATE = 0.00025/4
DENSE_PARAMS = [256]

class Network():
    def __init__(self, state_size=OBSERVATION_SPACE_VALUES, action_size=ACTION_SPACE_SIZE, learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,    
                 dense_params=DENSE_PARAMS):

        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate= learning_rate        
        self.model = self.create_model(dense_params)

    def create_model(self, dense_params=[256]):

        model = Sequential()
        for params in dense_params:
            units = params
            model.add(Dense(units, activation='relu',input_shape=[self.state_size]))

        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation="linear"))
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

Agent = Network()

for i in range(10_000):
    state = np.random.rand(Agent.state_size)
    state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)
    output = np.random.rand(Agent.action_size)
    output = np.expand_dims(output, axis=0)
    Agent.model.fit(state,output,verbose=True)
```

And also:

```
tf.__version__
2.0.0
tf.keras.__version__
2.2.4-tf
```

Comment: `range(10_000)`??

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the use of multiple `.fit` calls. To solve this, you can either:

- create a data_generator of your data and call `.fit(epochs=10000)`

or

- keep the for loop but call `train_on_batch [(doc)](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) instead

Comment: `.fit` calls have nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Hi Raphael. Thanks for the reply. Thing is in the actual script that I'm interested I need to have fit in a loop because I do a lot of other stuff that gather data (it's an RL algorithm) so I can't just have epochs instead of a loop. I just found out that this seems to be the problem in the specific version of tf.keras and the same thing happens with predict. Possible solutions are to replace predict and fit with predict on_batch and train_on_batch, although they are not ideal, so I'll leave the question open